# Angular copy doesn't keep client up to date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a simple add post and comments app with https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack/wiring-everything-up. After finishing this section I should be able to add a post or comment and it save to the database and bind on the client side at the same time to keep the information current. However, it is only posting to the back end correctly and is not populating the post or comments array with the ng-model data. I believe the problem may be with the angular copy in the post service but do not see an error. The only difference I can see in my code and the tutorial is that it wanted to use .success for the callback of $http which I think is deprecated so I use .then instead. Below I will post the service, control, and ng-template, if you would like more information I can send a link to the repository.

Edit:Also I should note I know that it is working in the back end because I can see it in the collection or I can also manually refresh the browser and the new post is there. But obviously I shouldn't need to do a refresh.

Service

```
app.factory('posts', ['$http', function($http){
var o = {
    posts:[]
}

o.get = function(id){
    return $http.get('/posts/' + id).then(function(res){
        return res.data;
    });    
};

o.getAll = function() {
    return $http.get('/posts').then(function(data){
        angular.copy(data.data, o.posts);
    });
  };

o.create = function(post) {
  return $http.post('/posts', post).then(function(data){
    o.posts.push(data);
  });
};

o.upvote = function(post){
    return $http.put('/posts/'+ post._id + '/upvote').then(function(data){
        post.upvotes +=1;
    });
}

o.addComment = function(id, comment){
    return $http.post('/posts/' + id + '/comments', comment);
};

o.upvoteComment = function(post, comment){
    return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/comments/' + comment._id + '/upvote')
        .then(function(data){
            comment.upvotes += 1;
        });
};

return o;

}])
```

Controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts', function($scope, posts){
$scope.test = 'Hello world!';

$scope.posts = posts.posts;

$scope.addPost = function(){
    if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
    posts.create({
      title: $scope.title,
      link: $scope.link
    });
    $scope.title='';
    $scope.link='';
}

$scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
  posts.upvote(post)
};

}]);
```

ng-template

```
<script type='text/ng-template' id='/home.html'>
   <div class='page-header'>
             <h1>Rawle News App</h1>
          </div><!--End of page-header-->

          <div ng-repeat='post in posts | orderBy: "-upvotes"'>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
              ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
            {{post.upvotes}}
            <span class='link-titles'>
              <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
                {{post.title}}
              </a>
              <span ng-hide="post.link">
                {{post.title}}
              </span>
              <span>
                <a href="#!/posts/{{post._id}}">Comments</a>
              </span>
            </span>
          </div>  

          <form class='post-form' ng-submit='addPost()'>
              <div class='form-group'>
                 <input type='text' placeholder='title' ng-model='title'></input> 
              </div><!--End of form-group-->
              <div class='form-group'>
                 <input type='text' placeholder='link' ng-model='link'></input> 
              </div><!--End of form-group-->
            <button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>Post</button>
          </form> 
</script>
```

Comment: in `o.create` in `posts` service, do you return the post you created from the server? right now, you only add the return values to the `o` array here: `return $http.post('/posts', post).then(function(data){` (the callback in `then`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `post.create` function is erroneous:

```
//ERRONEOUS
/*
o.create = function(post) {
  return $http.post('/posts', post).then(function(data){
    o.posts.push(data);
  });
};
*/

//PUSH response.data
o.create = function(post) {
  return $http.post('/posts', post).then(function(response){
    o.posts.push(response.data);
    //return value for chaining
    return response.data
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller.

```
$scope.addPost = function(){
    if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
    posts.create({
        title: $scope.title,
        link: $scope.link
    }).then(function(){
        $scope.posts=posts.getAll();
    });
```

Can you try this too please try this BEFORE:

```
$scope.addPost = function(){
    if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
    posts.create({
        title: $scope.title,
        link: $scope.link
    }).then(function(){
        $scope.$apply();
    });
```

Comment: If it doesn't work tell me and I will show you another solution. Forgot the first option because you getAll return a promise too. If it works please vote up!

Comment: Thanks Sphinkx117, I did try both solutions you posted first before trying the others but unfortunately it did not fix it. Which was surprising to me because I'm not sure why $scope.posts = posts.getAll() doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

`o.getAll = function() {
  return $http.get('/posts').then(function(data){
      angular.copy(data.data, o.posts);
  });
};`

The above won't work as you're not returning anything from the `then()` statement.

`o.getAll = function() {
  return $http.get('/posts').then(function(data){
      return angular.copy(data.data, o.posts);
  });
};`

Should get you closer.

Keep in mind that anytime you're in async land (returning promises etc) you need to handle it correctly in your controller/service/directive/whatever.

Side question, why are you still using $scope as opposed to controller instance `as`?  This pattern has long been out of favor. Version of Angular?

Comment: Thanks for the post. I wanted this to be the solution because it strayed the least from the tutorial I'm working through but it did not reflect the change. Not a problem George solution worked but I thought I'd answer back that I haven't spent much time in angular but am familiar with controllerAs. This tutorial didn't use it and I didn't want to code something different and not be able to keep up with the tutorial since my main goal is to learn using jwtTokens with angular.